# Assigning values to an object inside a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, foreach, nuxt.js

I have a page on my website where i retrieve 1 project from the Firebase  Cloud Firestore. This website is being made with Vue.js and Nuxt.js. I am getting this project thru an API that me and my friend made with Express.js. On the page there is a gallery with images, i want to use the package `Photoswipe` to be able to swipe thru the images, but i need the image dimentions for that. Since i cannot set the dimentions when i am saving my document to firebase i am trying to get the image dimentions when recieving the project inside the API. I am trying to do this by using the package `probe-image-size` inside a foreach loop that loops thru all the gallery images.

My problem is that i cannot seem to set the dimention values to the `data` object from the inside of the `.then()` promise.

I have tried returning values from inside the promise, but that does not seem to work for me.

this is the API endpoint for getting a specific project:

```
router.get('/:id', api(async req => {
  let item, doc = null

  try {
    doc = await collection.doc(req.params.id).get()
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`Error getting project ${req.params.id}:`, error);
  }

  if (doc && doc.exists) {

    const data = doc.data()


    const probe_promises = data.images.map(image => probe(image.url).then(res => {
      image.width = res.width;
      image.height = res.height;
    }))

    await Promise.all(probe_promises)

    console.log(data.images);

    item = data
  }

  return item
}));
```

This is the part that is throwing the `Request failed with status code 500` error, without this part the code works fine:

```
const probe_promises = data.images.map(image => probe(image.url).then(res => {
      image.width = res.width;
      image.height = res.height;
    }))

    await Promise.all(probe_promises)

    console.log(data.images);
```

this is the exact error that it is throwing:

```
 Request failed with status code 500
[0] 
[0]   at createError (node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
[0]   at settle (node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
[0]   at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:237:11)
[0]   at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:15)
[0]   at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:471:20)
[0]   at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1161:12)
[0]   at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
```

The weird thing is that when i remove the `probe` code and reload the page, then add the code again and reload the page again it works.

Comment: Don't use `then` manually, this is what `await` is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some Promise usage errors. Don't mix `async/await` with  `then/catch`, or at least do it only when you are forced to.

The `array.foreach()` doesn't wait for promises but start them without do anything else. A solution is to `map` all the promises and then wait for them.

```
router.get('/:id', api(async req => {
  let item, doc = null

  try {
    doc = await collection.doc(req.params.id).get()
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`Error getting project ${req.params.id}:`, error);
  }

  if (doc && doc.exists) {

      const data = doc.data()

      probe_promises = data.images.map(image => probe(image.url).then(res => {
        image.width = res.width;
        image.height = res.height;
      }))

      await Promise.all(probe_promises)

      console.log(data.images);
      item = data
  }

  return item
}));
```

Comment: Unfortunately your code throws an error : `Request failed with status code 500`

Comment: Unfortunately i don't know the rest of your code, so it can be an image without url, the probe function, res.width or heigth. If you post more detail we can find out what is the problem.

Comment: I edited my post with some useful info. I also posted the part where i think the code throws the error.

Comment: Turns out my Firebase Cloud Storage rules were preventing me from viewing certain files if i was not authenticated. Now that i changed the rules the code you wrote works perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's not how you should use Promises: item callback called asynchronously. It means you return item before it will be assigned in this callback. To get promise value in the caller function you just need to return item from promise and return this promise from `router.get()` function.